# Is it possible to process a FBO's color attachement (texture) using a fragment/pixel shader without vertex shader?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

Im currently playing around with some terrain-generation stuff using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS devices. I have a texture and a heightmap. What I want to do is blur the terrain's texture using a fragment shader, but not on every draw call (just on demand and at the beginning). This is why I decided to process the blurring offscreen inside a FBO and then attach this FBO as a texture to the terrain. Now I'm wondering if it is possible to just add the image(texture) as a color attachement to a newly generated FBO and process it with a fragment shader? Or is there a better approach? No projection, lightning etc. is needed.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to line up with what you ended up saying. Could you clarify?

Comment: In other words: Is it possible to use a fragment shader on a color attachement without having any vertices defined? Or do I really have to upload a rectangle consisting of 4 vertices, map the texture coords and then finally do the image processing stuff in the fragment shader?

Comment: Ok, sorry guys my fault. I completely missunderstood the sense of a FBO's color attachement. ^^ A FBO's color attachement doesn't receive a texture, that can be mapped or processed. It is the outputted texture after the FBO got rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't circumvent a vertex shader and have your fragment shader do anything. There are plenty of ways to minimize how much the vertex shader does - you can just pass the geometry right through to the fragment shader. Shaders like that are usually called (unsurprisingly) "pass-through shaders" because they just shuffle information on to the next piece of the pipeline without doing a whole lot.

Comment: Wanted just to add that in modern (desktop) OpenGL you can do smth called "Vertex Pulling" ,that is loading vertex data with texture arrays rather than using standard vertex attributes.But still,it happens in vertex shader.There is no way bypass this stage.